# Visual studio code - find all references

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've imported a folder with many *.c and *.h files into VSC (also many subfolders).
When I try to find all references to a global variable / function or anything else I get an empty results window.
Is there a configuration that I need to perform in order to make find all references work? Do you I need to build the project differently (I've simply opened the folder with source files into VSC)?

Thanks.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52677651/find-all-references-across-files-for-a-method-function-in-vscode-is-not-possib

Answer (score 0):

In summary, you need to install the [Microsoft C/C++ Extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp) and [GNU Global](http://www.gnu.org/software/global/download.html) and run `gtags` on your workspace folder. You can see a more [detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57073947/5362795) for the steps.